# How to simplify multiple functions that have different ids

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simplify the following code:

```
var filesystem = new fp.FloorplanFilesystem(myFloorplan, fp.FILESYSTEM_UI_STATE);
        document.getElementById("newFloorplan").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            filesystem.newFloorplan();
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        document.getElementById("showOpenWindow").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            filesystem.showOpenWindow();
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        document.getElementById("saveFloorplan").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            filesystem.saveFloorplan();
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        document.getElementById("saveFloorplanAs").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            filesystem.saveFloorplanAs();
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        document.getElementById("showRemoveWindow").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            filesystem.showRemoveWindow();
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

It's starting to take up a lot of room and look messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call wrapper function with dynamic values for ID and function name:

```
var filesystem = new fp.FloorplanFilesystem(myFloorplan, fp.FILESYSTEM_UI_STATE);

function bindEvent(id, callbackFunction) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', function (event)) {
        event.preventDefault();

        filesystem[callbackFunction]();
    }
}

bindEvent('newFloorplan', 'newFloorplan');
bindEvent('showOpenWindow', 'showOpenWindow');
...
```

Comment: I would prefer to use in bindEvent callback, not function name: use:
callbackFunction(); 
and then: 
bindEvent('newFloorplan', filesystem.newFloorplan);
In this way bindEvent will be more generic :).

Comment: @GrzesiekDanowski you'd need to use `filesystem.newFloorplan.bind(filesystem)` to make that work properly.

Comment: Awesome, Thank You-

Comment: Can I use this method for something like this:  'var ui = new fp.FloorplanUI(myFloorplan, "ui", "myFloorplan", fp.GUI_STATE);
            function bindEvent(id, floorplanUIFunction, div) {
                document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    ui[floorplanUIFunction]([div]);
                });
            }

            bindEvent('diagramHelpDivButton', 'hideShow', 'diagramHelpDiv');'

Answer (score 1):

You can access the property of an object by a variable containing a string using bracket notation.

```js
var filesystem = new fp.FloorplanFilesystem(myFloorplan, fp.FILESYSTEM_UI_STATE);

["newFloorplan", "showOpenWindow", "saveFloorplan", "saveFloorplanAs", "showRemoveWindow"].forEach(function(id){
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    filesystem[id]();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filesystem = new fp.FloorplanFilesystem (myFloorplan, fp.FILESYSTEM_UI_STATE)

const ids = ['newFloorplan', 'showOpenWindow', 'saveFloorplan', 'saveFloorplanAs', 'showRemoveWindow']
const handler = id => event => (filesystem [id] (), event.preventDefault ())

ids.forEach (id => document.getElementById (id).addEventListener ('click', handler (id)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your elements use the name of the function that you want to invoke as their ID, you can extract that within the event handler:

```
var filesystem = new fp.FloorplanFilesystem(myFloorplan, fp.FILESYSTEM_UI_STATE);

function fs_handler(event) {
    filesystem[event.target.id]();
    event.preventDefault();
}

["newFloorplan", "showOpenWindow", "saveFloorplan", "saveFloorplanAs", "showRemoveWindow"].forEach(function(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventHandler('click', fs_handler);
});
```

This should be generally preferred over creating a new callback function object for each item.

Furthermore, if the clickable elements all share a common parent, you could just register the event handler on that, via [*event delegation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target#Example), saving the need to register each button individually.

Answer (score 0):

My proposition (es6) - "code from head":

```
[
  "newFloorplan", 
  "showOpenWindow", 
  "saveFloorplan", 
  "saveFloorplanAs", 
  "showRemoveWindow",
].map(id=>document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', event=>{
  filesystem[id](); 
  event.preventDefault()
}));
```